# Why can I edit everyone's posts?

Tags: support, editing

I do not have 50 reputation to comment, but I can click "edit" everywhere.

Of course, I do not modify other people's posts, but why can I do this?

Comment: You can click "edit" but your changes will be reviewed by users with enough reputation, then accepted or rejected. You can change your own posts without review.

Comment: Editing questions allows you to earn reputation. You get +2 reputation for each edit that gets approved. You can also earn reputation by answering a question or asking a good computer related question. If you get an up vote on an answer, you'll get +10 reputation for each up vote it receives. If the question asker chooses your answer as the best answer, you get +15 reputation.

Comment: I see. the changes will be reviewed...

Answer (score 7):

You can do this because we allow anyone to make an attempt to make the site a better place.

Until you reach [2000 reputation](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/edit) your edits will be community reviewed. This means that a new user cannot simply wander on to the site and start vandalizing everything in sight. If they did then it is likely they would quickly be banned from suggesting edits as well.

Accepted edits can also earn you 2 reputation per edit, up to a 1000 total contribution to your rep, so they can be a small way to get started on the site. There are better ways to get rep, like providing great answers, but edits can be a minor filler.